# Django Okta Integration

Tags: django, okta

I have a few questions about integrating Okta with Django.

I've noticed that it is quite easy to setup authorization and authentication in Flask Applications by using OpenID Connect (a library already defined in Flask) and Okta.

1. Is there something similar in Django? (i.e. an OpenID Library built in or easily added)
2. Are there any other ways to integrate Okta with Django besides using OpenID?

I've looked at all of the available get github repositories and post regarding this and they're either: outdated or not working correctly.

Answer (score 1):

An easy way to integrate OpenID Connect in Django is via this Mozilla library: https://github.com/mozilla/mozilla-django-oidc. See also here for an overview of Django OIDC options: https://djangopackages.org/grids/g/oidc/.

Another option to integrate Okta with Django would be by using SAML. For example by using this Django library: https://github.com/fangli/django-saml2-auth

See also this Okta article explaining the difference between the OIDC and SAML: https://www.okta.com/identity-101/whats-the-difference-between-oauth-openid-connect-and-saml/